# Can all Z-estimators be written as M-estimators?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be i.i.d. random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}^p$, and $m_\theta,\psi_\theta:\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$.
An $M$-estimator is any element of:
$$
\arg\min_{\theta\in\Theta}\sum_{i=1}^nm_\theta(x_i)
$$
A $Z$-estimator is any zero of:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\psi_\theta(x_i)=0
$$
In some cases, those two concepts are equivalent: e.g. given $m_\theta$, one can find $\psi_\theta$, such that an $M$-estimator is also a $Z$-estimator if $\theta\mapsto m_\theta$ convex and differentiable.

I am wondering whether one can always write a $Z$-estimator as an $M$-estimator.
More precisely: Fix any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any collection of functions $\{\psi_\theta,\theta\in\Theta\}$, such that a $Z$-estimator exists (almost surely).
Are there functions $m_\theta$, such that for (almost) all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^p$,
$$
\left\{\theta\in\Theta:\sum_{i=1}^n\psi_\theta(x_i)=0\right\}=\arg\min_{\theta\in\Theta}\sum_{i=1}^n m_\theta(x_i)
$$

Comment: You can always write is as a quadratic in the sense that you maximize the objective function $-|\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi_\theta(X_i) |$, which is maximized at a the zero of your $Z$-estimator. This is usually still viewed as an $M$-estimator but does not fit the narrower definition you gave. The equality that you are looking for is generally false, although I can't give a very simple counterexample. Median regression with instrumental variables can be written as a moment condition that leads to a $Z$ estimator but does not have a corresponding $M$-estimator that is a sum of $m_\theta(X_i)$ terms.